# Java 8 Stream API how to reuse custom method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method like:

```
private List<Person> findFilteredPersons(List<Person> persons,
            Predicate<Person> filter) {
        return persons
                .stream()
                .filter(filter)
                .sorted(BY_NAME.thenComparing(BY_AGE))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now I would like to use this method in several places, but in one place I don't need to filter the list, I just want to sort it. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Pass a predicate that takes all items? That's as good as not filtering.

Comment: I've thought about that, but it seems suboptimal (readability of code and performance) to filter a list when you know you want all results...

Comment: Are you running into performance issues? Because premature optimization is a bad practice.

Comment: No, but since the question is quite general I thought I'd mention this concern. Also I'm not sure if it will be immediately apparent that nothing gets filtered...

Comment: You can create another method that informs this by it's name, but re-uses this method (so the code is not duplicated). Check out my answer.

Comment: very true :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s unlikely that you will run into performance issue when simply using a `x -> true` predicate to indicate “no filtering”, however, if you want to express the unfiltered operation as such for clarity, the solution is straight-forward: as always for such kind of code organization, split the operation into the distinct parts and the common part:

```
private List<Person> findFilteredPersons(List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> filter) {
    return collectSortedPersons(persons.stream().filter(filter));
}
private List<Person> findPersons(List<Person> persons) {
    return collectSortedPersons(persons.stream());
}
private List<Person> collectSortedPersons(Stream<Person> persons) {
    return persons
            .sorted(BY_NAME.thenComparing(BY_AGE))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To take all items (practically ignoring the filter), pass a predicate that takes all people:

```
p -> true
```

You can create another method:

```
private List<Person> findPeople(List<Person> persons) {
    return findFilteredPersons(persons, p -> true);
}
```